# The hundredth switch and the tau function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> An electronic controller has 100 switches, initially all set to the closed position.
>
> - In the first run across the switches, they are all opened.
> - Then in the next run, every second switch is changed; the others are left as is. (So, for example, after this second run, switch number 1 is open, and switch number 2 and 96 are closed.)
> - Then on the third run though, every third switch is changed. (So switch number 3 is closed and switch number 6 is open.)
> - On the fourth run, every fourth switch is changed.
> - This carries on until the 100th run, in which every 100th switch is changed.
>
> At the end of all this, is switch number 100 open or closed?
>   Explain how the solution to this problem is connected to the $\tau$ function from question 5.

---

> **Question 5** Let $\tau :\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ be the function where the output is the number of positive integer factors of the input. For example, $\tau(15)=4$ since there are 4 positive integer factors of 15, namely 1, 3, 5, and 15.
>
> (a) Find $\tau(n)$ for all $n\in[1,20]$.
>   (b) Is $\tau$ an injective function?
>   (c) If $\tau(n)$ is odd, what can we say about $n$?
>   (d) If $p$ is a prime, what is $\tau(p)$?
>   (e) If $n=p^r$ where $p$ is prime and $r$ is a positive integer, find a formula for $\tau(n)$.
>   (f) Give a specific number $n$, if possible, such that $τ(n)=10017$. Is $\tau$ a surjective (onto) function?
>   (g) [advanced] Let $n=p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}\dots p_r^{n_r}$ where each $p_i$ is prime and each $n_i$ is a non-negative integer. Determine $\tau(n)$.

Here is my working:

- On the first run, every switch is flipped.
- On the second run, every switch divisible by 2 is flipped.
- On the third run, every switch divisible by 3 is flipped, etc.

So after 100 runs, the 100th switch will have been flipped once for every number that divides into 100. The factors of 100 are:

```
1 2 4 5 10 20 25 50 100
```

Since there are 9 factors of 100, the switch will have been flipped 9 times. 9, being odd, means that the switch is different from its original state, which is closed. Hence the 100th switch ends up open.

Am I in the right direction? How can I convey this mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

In words, you're proof seems to be correct, so I'll try to answer the second part of your question by giving some hints on how to proof it mathematically.

First, you invoke the [fundamental theorem of arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), that every positive number can be written as a unique product of primes, which you can label $p_0$ up to $p_n$. The uniqueness of the factorization is needed to make sure the number of factors, $n$, is well defined.

To prove that the switch is closed when $n$ is even and open when $n$ is odd can be done by a reasoning along the lines of: "If the switch is open and you have switched it an even amount of times and you switch it again, then the switch is closed and you will have switched it an odd amount of times" and similar for other cases. However, you can probably find a shorter formulation of the principle.

I hope this gives you enough information to write a nice proof for yourself. If not, feel free to ask!

Comment: I just realised that I answered the question if you don't know which switch it is. However you know it is the 100th switch, so your case is easier. I think your descrtiption then would already be pretty much correct in any math class, except perhaps for the uniqueness of the factorisation, which you implicitly used.

Comment: First of thank you for replying it means a lot. We touched upon fundamental theorem of arithmetic but we were mainly taught counting techniques. Could the application of combinatorics be used to prove this?

Comment: I don't think one needs the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to show that the factors of a non-square integer come in matching pairs, and the factors of a prefect square come in matching pairs except for the square root. And certainly the _number of factors_ is well defined even without uniqueness of factorizations -- it's just the cardinality of a certain finite set and doesn't care how we _find_ that cardinality.